# adding two relations to a rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a patient visit report migration here. I need to add the report to allow one patient has many reports, and one user (doctor) has many reports. The doctor patient relationship is already set up. How would i link the report to user, and patient

VisitReport.rb

```
 class CreateVisitReport < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :visit_reports do |t|
          t.text :date
          t.text :report

          t.timestamps
          end
      end
    end
```

Users.rb (Doctor)

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.string :encrypted_password, limit: 128, null: false
      t.string :confirmation_token, limit: 128
      t.string :remember_token, limit: 128, null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email
    add_index :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

Patient.rb

```
class CreatePatients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :patients do |t|

      t.string    :name,      null: false
      t.integer   :age,       null: false
      t.string    :phone,     null: false
      t.string    :ailment,   null: false
      t.datetime  :apointment,  null: false
      t.string    :status,    null: false

      t.belongs_to :user, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Jayk, thanks for your question. Please consider editing your question to show what you've already tried, and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, your `VisitReports` method will look like this, this called [`The has_many :through Association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

```
class CreateVisitReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :visit_reports do |t|
      t.text :date
      t.text :report

      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :patient, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
      end
  end
end
```

then `rake db:migrate`, if you need to create with a command then the command will look like this

```
rails g model VisitReport date:text report:text user:references patient:references
```

It will generate same which written above class.

Models look like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :visit_reports, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :patients, through: :visit_reports
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :visit_reports, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :visit_reports
end

class VisitReport < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :patient
end
```

If you already migrated the `visit_reports` table and not want to `rollback` then this table then type your command prompt like this

```
rails g migration add_index_to_visit_reports
```

then go to `db/migrate` and update look like this

```
class AddIndexToVisitReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :user, :visit_report, index: true
    add_reference :patient, :visit_report, index: true
  end
end
```

then `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks so much. Brilliant answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

add following columns into a VisitReport table

```
visit_reportable_type
visit_reportable_id
```

and modify your model's associations as follows

```
class User
    has_many :visit_reports, as: :visit_reportable
end

class Patient
    has_many :visit_reports, as: :visit_reportable
end
```